# How do to code an angular observable to return flat values when mapped

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, observable

I'm writing code where a customer is not allowed on a page if a value is set to true I now have working code but my gut tells me that it is not the most efficient use.

The code is:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    let bar= false;
    this.foo$.subscribe((x) => {
        bar = x;
    });

    return !bar;
}
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    return this.foo$.subscribe((x) => {
        return x;
    });
}
```

The problem is that it keeps returning a Observable if I use it like this and the canActivate function of the guard is not working whit this Observable.

Comment: your first code snippet won't work the way you expect it to. the second code snippet should work ok. what do you mean `guard is not working`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `this.foo$` is an `Observable<boolean>` then you could simply negate the boolean value in a `map()` function ([see documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map)) and return the resulting `Observable` like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    return this.foo$.map(x => !x);
}
```

Your first code snippet will not work reliably because of the asynchronous `foo$` subscription. The function will probably always return true, before the `foo$.subscribe()` method was called

Comment: well it works kind off the problem now is that the value of foo$ is loaded after the route is called is there a way to get the guard to act after this happens?

Comment: @A.Leenders depending on how you load `foo$` (e.g. via a service), you could just inject the required service into the Guard, and call it in the the `canActivate()`method manually.

Comment: we use ngrx for that but that is a different problem thanks for the help.